# How to access per-page variable/command for use in footer

Tags: macros, header-footer

What I would like to accomplish is **including a per-chapter variable/command in the header** (or footer, would be the same issue).

The real crux of this question is, I supposed: ***how would one include a command in the header/footer that is evaluated at runtime rather than when it is defined?***

In my particular use case, each chapter is "reviewed" independently, and I'd like to include the reviewed at date in the footer. These review dates are defined somewhere in the chapter (I've tried using `\let` and `\def` so far).

Minimal example below:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{accentcolor}{HTML}{D33900}
\definecolor{fadedgreycolor}{HTML}{888888}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{FED6C7}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=accentcolor]{hyperref}

\urlstyle{same}

% Chapter styles.
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{10pt}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\color{accentcolor}}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage{} \reviewedblurb}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage{} \reviewedblurb}

% Header/footer styles.
\copypagestyle{blah}{headings}
\makeevenhead{blah}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{blah}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{blah}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{blah}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage}
\nouppercaseheads
\makerunningwidth{blah}{\textwidth}
\makeheadrule{blah}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeheadfootruleprefix{blah}{\color{fadedgreycolor}}{\color{fadedgreycolor}}
\pagestyle{blah}

\newcommand{\reviewedblurb}{\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\lastreviewedon}}{}{Reviewed on: \lastreviewedon}}

\tightlists

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\def \lastreviewedon {August 07, 2015}

\chapter{This is the first Chapter}

\section{There are 8 key features in this topic:}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is item 1
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is sub item 1.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\def \lastreviewedon {July 07, 2015}

\chapter{This is the second Chapter}

\section{There are 5 key features in this topic:}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is item 1
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is sub item 1.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mention the *review date* is "defined *somewhere* in the chapter". So potentially you could have `\lastreviewedon` at the start, or the middle, or the end of the chapter, and wherever it is used, it should reflect that for the entire chapter?

Comment: Place `\lastrewiedon` in the definiton of `\makeevenhead` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following provides a `\label`-`\ref` approach to your "last reviewed date" display. It uses [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) to create a "property" called `lastrevieweddate` which stores the last known argument supplied to `\lastreviewedon{<stuff>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor,zref}
\definecolor{accentcolor}{HTML}{D33900}
\definecolor{fadedgreycolor}{HTML}{888888}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{FED6C7}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=accentcolor]{hyperref}

% Chapter styles.
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{10pt}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\color{accentcolor}}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage{} \reviewedblurb}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage{} \reviewedblurb}

% Header/footer styles.
\copypagestyle{blah}{headings}
\makeevenhead{blah}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{blah}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{blah}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{blah}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage}
\nouppercaseheads
\makerunningwidth{blah}{\textwidth}
\makeheadrule{blah}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeheadfootruleprefix{blah}{\color{fadedgreycolor}}{\color{fadedgreycolor}}
\pagestyle{blah}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{lastrevieweddate}[??]{\@empty}
\newcommand{\reviewedblurb}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{last-review-date-\thechapter}{}
    {\zref@def@extractdefault{\@lastrevieweddate}{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}{\@empty}%
     \ifx\@lastrevieweddate\@empty\else
       Reviewed on: \zref@extract{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}%
     \fi}}
\newcommand{\lastreviewedon}[1]{\zref@setcurrent{lastrevieweddate}{#1}}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}<1\else% Nothing to do before the first chapter
    \zref@labelbyprops{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}%
    \zref@setcurrent{lastrevieweddate}{}% Clear any review date references for the next chapter
  \fi
  \oldchapter% Resume old \chapter sequence
}
\AtEndDocument{\zref@labelbyprops{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lastreviewedon{August 07, 2015}% Last reviewed date noted at start of chapter
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]% No reviewed date specified

\chapter{Third chapter}
\lastreviewedon{January 01, 2015}% Multiple instances of last reviewed date
\lastreviewedon{January 02, 2015}% This will be used
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Fourth chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]
\lastreviewedon{July 07, 2015}% Last reviewed date noted at end of chapter

\end{document}
```

Since the approach is based on using (cross-) references, you can place `\lastreviewedon{<stuff>}` anywhere within the `\chapter` scope. Note that this also requires at least two compilations on the first go (typical of cross-reference usages). As a bonus, multiple instances are also allowed, with the last one used for reference.

Comment: This is amazing, I had no idea what the zref package even was. Thanks!