# zref variable is cached incorrectly in page header/footer when \setsecnumdepth{none}

Tags: header-footer, zref

Following on from this question:

[How to access per-page variable/command for use in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259309/how-to-access-per-page-variable-command-for-use-in-footer)

I'm using the `zref` package to provide custom, per-chapter variables in the page footer (namely, a "reviewed on:" date that changes per chapter).

Below, I've included a MWE that works as intended. If I attempt to remove chapter numbering using `\setsecnumdepth{none}`, the footer no longer works as intended - the "reviewed on" date on all chapters is set to the last-appearing call to set the date in `\lastreviewedon{...}`.

There's obviously some caching going on that I'm not understanding. Any help in achieving both of my goals (no chapter numbering, and per-chapter custom footer variables) would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass[9pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{accentcolor}{HTML}{D33900}
\definecolor{rememberbodycolor}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{fadedgreycolor}{HTML}{888888}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{F9E3DC}
\definecolor{textcolor}{HTML}{000000}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\openany
\checkandfixthelayout

% Chapter styles.
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{10pt}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\color{accentcolor}}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage{} \reviewedblurb{}}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage{} \reviewedblurb{}}

% Common styles.
\copypagestyle{mystyle}{headings}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{\color{fadedgreycolor}\thepage}
\nouppercaseheads
\makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\textwidth}
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeheadfootruleprefix{mystyle}{\color{fadedgreycolor}}{\color{fadedgreycolor}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

% Last Reviewed Date macro for putting in the footer.
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{lastrevieweddate}[??]{\@empty}
\newcommand{\reviewedblurb}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{last-review-date-\thechapter}{}
    {\zref@def@extractdefault{\@lastrevieweddate}{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}{\@empty}%
     \ifx\@lastrevieweddate\@empty\else
       --- Reviewed on: \zref@extract{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}%
     \fi}}
\newcommand{\lastreviewedon}[1]{\zref@setcurrent{lastrevieweddate}{#1}}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}<1\else% Nothing to do before the first chapter
    \zref@labelbyprops{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}%
    \zref@setcurrent{lastrevieweddate}{}% Clear any review date references for the next chapter
  \fi
  \oldchapter% Resume old \chapter sequence
}
\AtEndDocument{\zref@labelbyprops{last-review-date-\thechapter}{lastrevieweddate}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}
\lastreviewedon{November 13, 2015}

\lipsum

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lastreviewedon{September 20, 2015}

\lipsum

\chapter{Third Chapter}
\lastreviewedon{April 1, 2014}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\setsecnumdeph{none}`, the `chapter` counter is never stepped.

Comment: That makes sense - is there an alternative approach to achieving my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get 99% of what I wanted - I still have numbering of chapters in the table of contents (which I would rather not have), but I've been able to remove the numbering in the chapter titles while still allowing the chapter counter to tick up.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
```

Using the `titlesec` package will remove chapter numbering, and if I keep `\setsecnumdepth{chapter}` the `zref` references work as intended.